# Play mp4 videos one after another

Tags: video, mp4

Im using this code to call some videos:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Videos</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="videos/1_1.mp4" target="_blank">Video 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos/1_2.mp4" target="_blank">Video 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos/1_3.mp4" target="_blank">Video 03</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos/1_4.mp4" target="_blank">Video 04</a></li>      
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder if ther is anyway to play one video after another.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 `<video>` tag to embed the video in your page. Then set the `onended` event handler of that element to call a javascript function to change the `<source>` element(s) to the next video in the list and start it playing again.

See:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp
and
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp
(`onended` event handler is down in the 'Media Events' section)